Proving chain rule from Leibniz rule
Let $A$ be an algebra over an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. This means it has a vector sum and a vector product.
Let $F$ be the space of functions from $A$ to $A$. $F$ inherits the structure of an algebra, with sum and product defined pointwise.
Now define a new set of operators, $L$, defined to be the set of all linear operators from $F$ to $F$ that satisfy the Leibniz rule, $l(fg) = l(f)g + fl(g)$ where the product is the pointwise product. These are called derivations.
All $f$ in $F$ are from $A$ to $A$, so you can of course compose them.
Can you prove that an element $l$ in $L$ satisfies the chain rule, ie $l(g \circ f) = (l(g) \circ f)l(f)$ ?
If yes, what is the proof?
If not, what additional structure on $A$ and/or $F$ is needed for the chain rule to hold?

The chain rule is fairly easy to deduce when $g$ is a polynomial.

As currently stated this is (almost) vacuously true since there are no non-zero derivations on $F$
